# RailsのDeviseサインアップ時に、特定のメールアドレスにもメールを送信するやり方を教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**やりたいこと**

RailsのDeviseサインアップ時に、登録してくれたユーザのメールアドレスと、特定のメールアドレスにメールを送信するやり方を教えてください。

Deviseで新規登録時に

1. 登録してくれたユーザのメールアドレス
2. hogehoge@example.com

の2つにメールが届くようにしたいです。

登録してくれたユーザにはメールを送信できるのですが、特定のメールアドレス、「2」の「hogehoge@example.com」にもメールを送信するやり方がわかりません。どのように設定すれば良いのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Devise::Mailer` を継承したカスタムメーラクラスを作成し、その中で Cc を設定すると良いでしょう。

**config/initializers/devise.rb:**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.mailer = "MyMailer"
  ...
end
```

**app/mailers/my_mailer.rb:**

(全てのメールにCcを付ける場合)

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default :cc => "hogehoge@example.com"
end
```

(特定のメールにCcを付ける場合)

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    super(record, token, opts.merge(:cc => "hogehoge@example.com")
  end
end
```

※実際にはハードコーディングせず、別ファイルなどで定義するべきです。

参考:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer
- http://railsguides.jp/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: yasuさん、ありがとうございます！！
登録してくれたユーザのメールアドレスと、特定のメールアドレス(hogehoge@example.com)にメールを送信することが出来ました！！
全然分からなかったので、助けて頂いて感謝しておりますm(_ _)m